# How to calculate conditional probability

Tags: probability

How do I calculate

$$ 
P(Y \leq 1/4 | X > 1/2)
$$
if i know that 
$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 4x \ \ \ \text{if} \ 0 < y < x^2 \ \text{and} \ 0 < x < 1 \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
,
$$
f_X(x) =
\begin{cases} 4x^3 \ \ \ \text{if} \ 0 < x < 1 \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases} 2(1-y) \ \ \ \text{if} \ 0 < y < 1 \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I know that $P(Y \leq 1/4 | X > 1/2) = \frac{P(Y \leq 1/4 \cap X > 1/2)}{P(X > 1/2)}$
and that $P(X > 1/2) = \int_{1/2}^1 4x^3$ but how do I calculate the numerator when X and Y is not independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

integrate to compute the joint probability:

$P(Y \le 1/4, X > 1/2) = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} 4x dy dx = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 4 \frac{1}{4} x dx = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 xdx = \frac{3}{8}$

Comment: Okay it is that simple. Thanks!